# spring.datasource.password not working with docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application that connects to mysql db. For that I am using spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password in properties file. As long as I am using a static password defined against this property it works fine. But now I am trying to externalize the password property. For which I used

```
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
```

And in docker command I am passing this as an environment variable.

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" -e "DB_USER_PASSWORD=password" -t image:master
```

This is not picking password and I am always getting authentication exception. I also tried -e "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password" but that also did not work. What's weird is that when I pass password as parameter in my local machine, it works fine. I am using spring boot 2.2.6

Comment: Just to clarify - did you try using `-e "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password"` without having`spring.datasource.password=${DB_USER_PASSWORD}` in application.yml?

Comment: yes. I commented out spring.datasource.password when trying SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD

Comment: try `JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.datasource.password= password ` as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/)

Comment: that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

The password contained a $ character. That is why the environment variables were not getting properly configured.

Comment: Hi Devesh, glad you got it resolved. I recommend to [accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) in a couple days.

Comment: Regarding the cause of problem, I recommend to use single quotes for shell arguments by default, only switching to use double quotes in those cases when you are intentionally using single quotes or special expansion characters like `$` or a backtick. This is much more likely to prevent accidental injections or syntax errors. For bash, [here's a manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) about what could cause problems in single quotes.